Where does free ammonium in peripheral tissues come from if oxidative deamination occurs in the liver?
I have a misunderstanding regarding how some claims about amino acids catabolism make sense together. Maybe one of the claims is incorrect by itself so I'd be happy to be corrected. Here is what I don't get:
It is said that in amino acids catablosim, first the amino acids in peripheral tissues transfer their ammonium to alpha-keto-glutarate to form glutamate (with the help of aminotransferase), and that the deamination of the ammonium from the glutamate is carried by glutamate dehydrogenase in the mitochondria. But it is also said that this second step occurs in liver, and that in order to transport glutamate do the liver, it should be converted to glutamine using free ammonium by glutamine synthase.
If so, where is that free ammonium in peripheral tissues come from, if oxidative deamination by glutamate dehydrogenase occurs in the liver? why do we even say that free ammonium is generated in peripheral tissues in the first place?
I thought that the free ammonium come from other processes, but it is generally said that the whole point of this process is to clean free ammonium from peripheral cells. Also I tried looking the internet but I found only more contradictions. I'm sure I have some misconception here and hope for a clarification, thanks in advance

Welcome to SE. Biology. Please do us the courtesy of finishing the [Tour]. Your question is full of statements about vague “claims” you have read and things that “are said”, but the world is full of nonsense, so if you want a response here, you need to document your questions by quoting the sources verbatim, and stating where they are from. This helps us see their context and also makes you reflect on what is actually written.
